# Qual é a diferença entre essas duas declarações?

Tags: variáveis, swift, declaração-de-variável

Digamos que eu criei uma `struct` ponto que dá um certo ponto num "mapa".

```swift
struct Ponto {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
```

Qual seria a diferença entre criar uma variável do tipo `Ponto` e criar uma variável que contenha `Ponto` como valor?

```swift
var ponto1: Ponto

//e

var ponto2 = Ponto(x: 1, y: -1)
```

Comment: Não precisa implementar o init basic usando structures. `struct Ponto {
    let x, y: Int }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duas estão criando uma variável do tipo `Ponto`, a primeira não cria uma instância do objeto do tipo `Ponto` e se tentar acessar em seguida dará um erro de compilação, se inicializar depois da declaração funcionará normalmente:

```
struct Ponto {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
    }
}
var ponto1: Ponto;
ponto1 = Ponto(x: 1, y: -1);
print(ponto1.x, ponto1.y);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Initialization.c).

O segundo cria e inicializa o objeto com valores passados no construtor (o `init()`) que faz o que ele tem que fazer para inicializar. No caso ele passou argumentos nomeados que é a cultura de Swift para deixar mais legível.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro é declaração do tipo `var ponto1: Ponto`, ou seja, só está dizendo que a variável `ponto1` é do tipo `Ponto` e não há uma instância, já a outra `var ponto2 = Ponto(x: 1, y: -1)` é a instância de `Ponto` na variável `ponto2`, tem que tomar cuidado porque a `ponto1` não é uma instância e consequentemente não tem acesso aos seus membros.

```
struct Ponto {
  let x: Int
  let y: Int

  init(x: Int, y: Int) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  }
}

var ponto1: Ponto = Ponto(x: 6,y: 3); // tipo e depois instância
var ponto2 = Ponto(x: 100, y: 200); // instância

print(ponto1.x);
```

[Exemplo Online](https://repl.it/repls/SizzlingFrankCode)

---

O que pude perceber também que segue uma nomenclatura onde para ter um membro inicial padrão com uma sobrecarga de construtor tem que fazer dessa forma:

```
struct Ponto {
  let x: Int;
  let y: Int;
  init() {
    self.x = 0;
    self.y = 0;
  }
  init(x: Int, y: Int) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  }
}
```

e no caso da sua instância trabalhar assim:

```
var ponto0 = Ponto(); // valor padrão
var ponto1 = Ponto(x: 6,y: 3); // valor pelo construtor
```

---

Saída:

```
print(ponto0.x); // 0
print(ponto1.x); // 6
```

[Exemplo Online](https://repl.it/repls/AbsoluteLimpingWeb)

Se quiser somente ter os membros com valores padrões não precisa criar o construtor e passe diretamente os valores nos membros e troque `let` ([que define uma constante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)) por `var` ([que define uma variável](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)) na declaração:

```
struct Ponto {
  var x: Int = 0;
  var y: Int = 0;
}

var ponto1: Ponto = Ponto();
var ponto2 = Ponto();

print(ponto1.x); // 0
print(ponto2.x); // 0
```

---

*Realmente são vários conceitos que precisa entender e recomendo uma lida na documentação.*

---

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Initialization - swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)
- [Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)